# How to run m4 inline

Tags: preprocessor, m4

I have the following to process a file:

```
$ vim file2
define(add2, `eval($1+$2)')
Adding 2+4=add2(2,4)
```

And to run:

```
$ m4 file
Adding 2+4=6
```

Is there a way to run `m4` with the file contents inline? For example something like:

```
$ m4 <inline>
define(add2, `eval($1+$2)')
Adding 2+4=add2(2,4)
<ctrl-d>
# Adding 2+4=6
```

How could that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to the 'interactive mode':

> ```
>   -e, --interactive
>      unbuffer output, ignore interrupts
> ```

In which case you can do:

```
IM-MM:DD_Objects david$ m4 -e
define(add2, `eval($1+$2)')
Adding 2+4=add2(2,4)

Adding 2+4=6
```